# Linq->Entities and foreign key table issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, foreign-keys, saving-data

C# and general programming noobie here.

I have two tables.  Property and Memo.  There can be many Memo's to a single Property.  I have, at least I think I do, the format of the object creation done correctly.  The issue I do have is the Memo object doesn't save with the Property object.  The Property object seems to save just fine.

---

*Since I am a stack-noobie, I cannot post images strait into the post, so I've uploaded a couple which show both my Entities Diagram and the Referential Constraint dialogue.*

**www.jmtland.com/Pics/Diagram.png**

**www.jmtland.com/Pics/Referential%20Constraint.png**

---

```
            MTDBEntities1 dc = new MTDBEntities1();

            Property newProp = new Property();
            newProp.Address = t_Address.Text.Trim();
            newProp.City = t_City.Text.Trim();
            newProp.State = t_State.Text.Trim();
            newProp.Zip = t_Zip.Text.ToString();
            newProp.PropertyType = cb_PropertyType.Text.Trim();
            if (t_SizeMin.Text.Trim().Length != 0) { newProp.SizeMin = Convert.ToInt64(t_SizeMin.Text); }          // SizeMin is not required, so it won't be passed to the DB if there is no value.
            newProp.SizeMax = Convert.ToInt64(t_SizeMax.Text);
            newProp.SizeMetric = cb_SizeType.Text.Trim();
            if (t_PriceMin.Text.Trim().Length != 0) { newProp.PriceMin = Convert.ToDecimal(t_PriceMin.Text); }     // PriceMin is not required, so it won't be passed to the DB if there is no value.
            newProp.PriceMax = Convert.ToDecimal(t_PriceMax.Text);
            newProp.LeaseType = cb_LeaseType.Text.Trim();
            newProp.WebLink = t_WebLink.Text.Trim();
            newProp.Deleted = false;
            newProp.DateDeleted = null;
            newProp.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;

            Memo newMemo = new Memo();
            newMemo.Memo1 = t_PropertyMemo.Text.Trim();
            newMemo.MemoDateCreated = DateTime.Now;

            newProp.Memos.Add(newMemo);
            dc.AddToProperties(newProp);
            dc.SaveChanges();
```

I've been searching around for a fix for this problem for the last two days on multiple forums.  I've followed so many examples that I almost forgot my original code.

Sorry for the noobness.

Update:
I have tried saving the Property Table first, then the Memo table.
-Doesn't work either.

I have run through the debugger and there seems to be data associated with the Memo object as well as the Property object contains the Memo object in question but it, for some reason, doesn't save at the same time.

I've though about a different way around it, where I could save the property, then do a new query to get the PropertID of that new object, then force save the Memo object with the PropertyID returned.

The issue I have with that method is that would mean my understanding of the Entity framework wouldn't be correct.  I'd probably be able to hack my way around it but if I can't get it to work properly from the beginning, I fear that my later implementation of the same tech will be hindered by my inability to get it right from the get go.  I've dabbled in programming before and the one thing I've learned is if you don't learn the basics right the first time, the rest of your experience can be corrupted.

Comment: You're trying to "save" to a database, right?  Have you called `SaveChanges()` somewhere else? I don't see that here.

Comment: There was a mistake in my c/p and dc.SaveChanges(); didn't make it into the code block.  It's just below it.

Comment: Oh never mind, it's there; please make sure it's inside the code section.

Comment: Do you have a navigational property called "Memos" on the "Property" entity on your EDMX? I think the last line should be `dc.Properties.AddObject(newProp)`

Comment: Wouldn't you need to save the new property before you save its memo?

Comment: From my understanding, you can add the Memo object as part of the Property object, then they both get saved at the same time with the FK auto-generated.  I HAVE tried doing multiple .SaveChanges(); calls with no success.

Comment: @Josh, I think you might need to add the Memo object using `dc.Memos.AddObject(memo)`.   entity framework doesn't know that it needs to create new memo objects when it have just modified the navigational property of the property object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from RPM1984 seems to have worked.  I don't know why that worked over what I tried but whatever, I can now move onto my next 4 hour block of programming a single method!

> Do you have a navigational property
>   called "Memos" on the "Property"
>   entity on your EDMX? I think the last
>   line should be
>   dc.Properties.AddObject(newProp) –
>   RPM1984 5 hours ago